# Rule for leaving some particular amount of the white space on the bottom of the page. UX

Tags: website-design, user-experience, white-space

**Is there any rule for leaving some particular amount of the white space on the bottom of the page?** Or having the footer with a specific size? Especially for allowing users scrolling text of the website from the bottom of the website to the middle - to read it more easily.

I am always expecting it on websites and now I am creating one and other people in the team don't think it is needed. I am wondering if it is just my preference or:

Is there any UX rule or a good practice about letting people to scroll text higher by adding white space on the bottom?

Comment: I personally like a footer when I'm browsing a website. It's not really a rule though.

Comment: I guess it makes sense if you wanted to put some navigation there so when you get to the bottom of the page you don't have to scroll up

Comment: White space is your *friend*. I voted to close this because it's really merely opinion. I, personally, never want anything resting right on the edge of a window, any window, other than perhaps an empty color (i.e. bleed). I much prefer padding or white space all the way around a window.

Comment: @Scott: If this question were too opinion-based to be answered in this format, the profession of a web or graphic designer would be a scam. Of course, what we have to offer is only an opinion, but it’s a well-informed opinion and we can provide arguments.

Comment: I see this no different than asking *"Should I use blue or red?"* - Pure opinion. *Every* instance is different and even well informed opinions can *not* be accurate without a *full and complete* understanding of the design in question and any possible restrictions or client demands. Slight subjectivity is one thing given the profession. However, *completely* subjectivity isn't really what StackExchange is about in my experience.

Comment: @Scott I am not asking what should I do. I am specifically asking whether there is a rule defining this in any of user experience design ideologies or patterns.   (and actually, those are sets of grouped opinions based on experiences and experiments). 
I am not asking what to do but whether the particular rule exists. There are rules about font spacing, types of fonts to use together and I am curious whether there are any rules regarding white space on the bottom of the website.

Answer (score 1):

If readability is desired, then white space is one tool a designer can use to aid the user. I am sure there are studies out there, but you can imagine the results.

What do you think would take longer to read:

1. two facing pages that have zero margins (full width and full height of text to the edge of the pages; or
2. two facing pages that have roomy white space around the paragraphs and all around the page edges?

The second scenario would enable much faster reading. The human eye can be easily distracted while reading. Any amount of friction, confusion, or hesitation will encumber the efficiency of reading.

But to answer the question: how much white space to allocate is a calculated-guess by the designer. There is no formula but this margin can be groomed based on the size of the page, the size of the font, font weight, leading, kerning, etc etc.

In your case, Agata, you don't have to reserve room for a footer, but please do not end the page with text slamming into the bottom of the viewer.